# UserDetailsService ignored by security configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have tried security configuration for spring webFlux as described in documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc-webflux.html#explicit-webflux-security-configuration

Security configuration ignores userDetailsServiceBean - i cannot login with user:pass, but may login with credentials from autoconfigurated

```
UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:

2019-04-22 11:29:24.571  INFO 12343 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: ff00a80a-d810-43d6-9c89-e861eb1bed96
```

My pom.xml (fragment):

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My security config:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebfluxSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .anyExchange().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .formLogin();
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
         UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                 .username("user")
                 .password("pass")
                 .roles("USER")
                 .build();
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
    }

}
```

1. Why security config ignores userDetailsService ?
2. Is there error in spring-security documentation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation. It's used for Servlet applications and isn't applied on WebFlux.
2. You might also consider defining a bean of type `UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager` in your WebFlux Configuration; such as the following:

   ```
   @Bean
   public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService detailsService) {
        return new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(detailsService);
   }
   ```

In your case, most probably, the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation configures a bean of type `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` which is the non-reactive variant of `ReactiveUserDetailsManager`.

**NOTE:** You can remove the following from your POM if you're planning to use WebFlux only: `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and `spring-boot-starter-web`

Comment: 1. "Remove the @EnableWebSecurity annotation" - no effect

Comment: 2. "You might also consider defining a bean of type UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager" - no effect

Comment: 3. exclude dependency 
   <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
   </dependency> 
- work.

Question update: how configure security if i want to use spring web mvc and spring webflux in one application  (later i will try use two security configuration - one for web mvc, another for webFlux)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I solved this problem by moving the WebSecurityConfig class to the same package where I have the class that runs the Spring boot application (@SpringBootApplication)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).